# f2py generated interface expects tuple instead of fortran callback

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

I created a f2py python interface for [PITCON7](https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/f_src/pitcon7/pitcon7.html) (`pitcon7.f90`). The interface exposes two functions `pitcon` and `dge_slv` from `pitcon7.f90`. `dge_slv` is passed as a callback to `pitcon`. However on executing a sample problem that invokes pitcon I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pitcon_problem01.py", line 91, in <module>
    result = run(30)
  File "pitcon_problem01.py", line 58, in run
    ierror, iwork, rwork, xr = pitcon(df, fpar, fx, ierror, ipar, iwork, liw, nvar, rwork, lrw, xr, dge_slv)
TypeError: interface.pitcon() argument 12 must be tuple, not fortran
```

The `pitcon7.pyf` file is posted to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/aFxXEqWM)

The sample problem `pitcon_propblem01.py` has also been posted to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/HW5HLbxK) . This is the python equivalent of the Fortran `pitcon7_test1.f90` from the same upstream source, linked above.

I do not see why the f2py interface expects the callback to be a tuple, since there does not seem to be any argument mismatch.

Comment: Not sure about details, but "ierror" seems specified as intent(out), so possibly not needed to be passed as an actual argument ? (it may be useful to check the signature by "print( pitcon.__doc__ )" etc)

Comment: @roygvib . That was a keen observation but does not seem to be the problem. Actually if I do not pass `ierror` there is an argument mismatch  "interface.error: failed in processing argument list for call-back slname ".